# References for prime counting formulas from Eugene Dickson's book

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

While reading Eugene Dickson's book History of the theory of numbers I came across following prime counting formulas:

1.[image]

2.[image]

3.[image]

I want the papers by the authors but a quick google search couldn't give me nothing.

It would be very nice if someone could provide me with the links. (pdf if available)

Answer (score 2):

As regards Andreoli's paper see this [link](http://operedigitali.lincei.it/rendicontiFMN/rol/visabs.php?lang=it&type=mat&fileId=3998). The paper is written in italian. This is a short summary in english.

If $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and different from $x=0,-1,-2.,\dots$ then the function $$\Phi(x)=\sin^2\left(\pi\frac{\Gamma(x)+1}{x}\right)+\sin^2(\pi x),$$
which is the sum of two squares, is zero if and only if
$$\begin{cases}
\sin(\pi x)=0\\
\sin\left(\pi\frac{\Gamma(x)+1}{x}\right)=0\\
x\not \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \mathbb{N}^+
\end{cases}\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
x\in\mathbb{N}^+\\
\frac{(x-1)!+1}{x}\in\mathbb{N}^+
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow \text{$x$ is a prime}$$
where we applied the [Wilson's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem). Since $\Phi$ is a analytic in a neighborhood of the segment $[1,n]$ with $n>1$, by the [Argument Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), for any simple contour $\gamma$ passing through $1$ and $n$ (not a prime) and sufficiently close to the *cut* $[1,n]$,
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{\Phi'(z)}{\Phi(z)}\, dz$$
gives the number of primes less than $n$.

Comment: thank you for the answer and translation! Also I want to ask for how asymptotic is given for kth power prime?

Comment: An asymptotic of the SUM of the $k$th powers prime is mentioned at the end of the paper, but it is not related to $\Phi$. BTW that part is not clear to me.